# Why is the parameter h called like this in the render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

On the [documentation of Vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX), it says that :

> Aliasing `createElement` to `h` is a common convention you’ll see in the Vue ecosystem and is actually required for JSX.

I am simply wondering why is it abbreviated specifically to `h` ?

Comment: h function is a concept of jsx -> to pass jsx h abbreviation is required thus the union of possible abbreviations is h, why they called it h - your hyper-text source seems valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer I got comes from [a response to an issue on the Vuejs templates project](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/29#issuecomment-312902539) by bjunc. Here is the explanation :

> As noted by Evan in [this issue reply](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/6), the meaning of h comes from hyperscript:
>
> > It comes from the term "hyperscript", which is commonly used in many virtual-dom implementations. "Hyperscript" itself stands for "script that generates HTML structures" because HTML is the acronym for "hyper-text markup language".